# Why is my graph's Y-axis not in the right order?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot a graph for a data frame that looks like this:

```
year week cases
2003    1     0
2003    2     0
2003    3    12
2003    4    23
2003    5    12
2003    6    16
2003    7    20
2003    8    13
2003    9     0
2003   10     0
2003   11    21
2003   12   133
2003   13     9
2003   14    22
```

Carrying data for 52 weeks running from 2003-2012.

Here's what running `dput(head(df,20)` gives me:

```
structure(list(year = c(2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 
2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 
2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L), week = 1:20, cases = c(2, 
2, 26, 146, 26, 70, 115, 37, 2, 2, 124, 41, 245, 135, 146, 163, 
26, 26, 92, 92)), .Names = c("year", "week", "cases"), row.names 1925:1944, class = "data.frame")
```

I want my Y-axis to be simply the range of the variable 'cases', and the X-axis to run from week 1 through 52. I want to plot every year's data points in a different color.

Here's my ggplot2 code:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=week, y=cases, col=year)) + geom_point()
```

This is the graph it's generating:

[image: graph]

Why is this happening? I see no reason why my Y-axis shouldn't just be the range of 'cases' in ascending order.

Comment: aren't your cases characters ? because your axis seems sorted to me, but in the order of the characters...

Comment: Oh I didn't think of that. How do I get it to read them as integers and not characters?

Comment: there is probably a "strange" value explaining the fact that R didn't recognise it directly as numeric so search for that. (eg try `as.numeric(df$cases)` and search for the NA value ;-) )

Comment: also it would probably be more appropriate to have a discrete scale for the years rather than the continuous scale you're using

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working sadly :(. I tried adding this line to my code `df$cases <- as.numeric(df$cases)`. It doesn't throw me any errors and I can see that the column type is `num`, but my graph still isn't changing.

Comment: what does `summary(df$cases)` tell you ? you can use `dput(head(df, 20))` if you want to edit your question with a sample of your real data.frame

Comment: `Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.` 
    `2.0    15.0   146.0   120.4   199.0   249.0`

Comment: yes it seems numeric... weird... are you sure you did summary on your former data ? because the summary says the max is 249 but you have 253 in your plot... (I get a "normal" plot with the data you put in your edit)

Comment: ok, I think your variable was a factor, then you changed it to numeric but got the levels of the factor. You need to get back your former data.frame and do `as.numeric(as.character(df$cases))`. Can you show the code your using to import your data ?

Comment: @GautamMainkar Did you call `summary` changing `df$cases` to `as.numeric(df$cases)`? Also, the `dput` is missing an `=` after row.names.

Comment: @CathG yes, that's exactly right, my variable was a factor which I changed to a numeric value. Are you saying I need to run this on my originally imported dataframe? The code I'm using to import is simply `df <- read.csv("file.csv", strip.white<-TRUE)` @blakeoft, yes I called `summary` after changing the type to numeric.

Comment: @CathG, adding the extra as.character() like you said worked! :) Thanks a lot. Could you repost your comment below so I can mark it correct?

Comment: @GautamMainkar, the best thing to do with your data would be 1. to understand why it was importing as character rather than numeric and 2. put stringsAsFactors=F to avoid having your character variable has factors ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To sum up what was said in the comments :

Your y-axis is indeed sorted but according to the character values (or rather the factor levels, as your variable was imported as factor) and not the numeric ones (so `1, 10, 11, ..., 2, 20, ...`)

There is 2 problems that need to be solved:
the first one is that you have to understand why the variable wasn't imported as numeric. You probably have a "strange" value (like `1,2` for example, ie a comma instead of a point as decimal separator)
The second one is you need numeric values to plot your data correctly. For that, you can transform your factor with `df$cases <- as.numeric(as.character(df$cases))`. ***Note that the strange value(s) will be converted to `NAs`, you may not want that.***

Just a final note, if you don't want your character variables to be imported as factors, you can use the parameter `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` in the import step.